# Printing JSON elements

Tags: python, json, yelp, yelp-fusion-api

There is something I don't understand about how to print a JSON element. With Yelp, thanks to this query "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?cc=FR&location=Toulouse&categories=movietheaters&limit=1" I can retrieve this JSON:

```
{
  "businesses": [
    {
      "id": "gaumont-wilson-toulouse-2",
      "name": "Gaumont Wilson",
      "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/dYJc874NnEJ9-jX2amrLvw/o.jpg",
      "is_closed": false,
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/gaumont-wilson-toulouse-2?adjust_creative=Xi9rQmCT871UpMvNRzAfuw&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=Xi9rQmCT871UpMvNRzAfuw",
      "review_count": 165,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "movietheaters",
          "title": "Cinema"
        }
      ],
      "rating": 4,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 43.6044154,
        "longitude": 1.4475916
      },
      "transactions": [],
      "location": {
        "address1": "3 place du Président Thomas Wilson",
        "address2": null,
        "address3": null,
        "city": "Toulouse",
        "zip_code": "31000",
        "country": "FR",
        "state": "31",
        "display_address": [
          "3 place du Président Thomas Wilson",
          "31000 Toulouse",
          "France"
        ]
      },
      "phone": "+33534445050",
      "display_phone": "+33 5 34 44 50 50",
      "distance": 451.43923036020004
    }
  ],
  "total": 11,
  "region": {
    "center": {
      "latitude": 43.602510035320684,
      "longitude": 1.4426422119140625
    }
  }
}
```

then I look into JSON this way:

```
response_data = response.json()
for i in response_data['businesses']:
    print i['name']
```

but the `'name'` is the only thing I can print!

I cannot print `'address1'`, `'city'` or `'zip_code'`.

Why?

Comment: Just a note - that isn't actually a JSON object. It's a dictionary - which, as you're discovering, is slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

```
for element in response_data['businesses']:
    id = element['id']
    name = element['name']
    city = element['location']['city']
    zip_code = element['location']['zip_code']
    state = element['location']['state']
    display_address = element['location']['display_address']
    latitude = element['coordinates']['latitude']
    longitude = element['coordinates']['longitude']
    phone = element['phone']

    print id, name,  city, zip_code, state, display_address, latitude, longitude, phone
```

Answer (score 0):

Because those keys do not exist at that hierarchy within the JSON. They exist within the dictionary against the `"location"` key. You'd want to use:

```
print i["name"]["location"]["address1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because those exist in the "location" sub-dictionary. You would need something like this:

`print i["name"]["location"]["address1"]`

to access the data.